# How to save an address to a smart_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I wanted to ask like we can do with a pointer.

```
int q = 10;
int* p = &q;
```

How to do something with  a shared_ptr? Can I use make_shared<> here?

```
shared_ptr<int> r = make_shared<int>(q);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: If `q` is a local variable, you should be careful as local variables tend to go out of scope. If it's a global variable, why do you need a smart pointer? In fact, why do you need a smart pointer here at all, what's your use-case? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Remember that `make_shared<T>(xs...)` invokes `T`'s constructor with `xs...`. In your case, `r` is a shared pointer to an heap-allocated object with value 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `shared_ptr` that owns a pointer, use the constructor directly:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> r(some_pointer_to_int);
```

If you want a `shared_ptr` that points to a copy of a given object, use `make_shared`:

```
auto r = std::make_shared<int>(some_int);
```

Note that the former would NOT be correct if the pointer points to an object with automatic storage duration. Such objects are managed by the runtime.

Comment: So if i have a local variable and I want to save address of its  copy to another pointer that is a private variable, then second method would be ok?

Comment: @tariqzafar Yes, the local variable will be copied into some object with dynamic storage duration, you'll get a `shared_ptr` that points to the copy, and the copy will be automatically destroyed when all `shared_ptr`s pointing to it are destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. Smart pointer is here for guaranteed deletion of the pointer(handle) around which it wraps. In your example you just take address of the local stack variable. Deletion of such a variable is undefined behavior(your app will crash most of the time).

But if your actual code is different and you truly want to keep an existing pointer(which is ok to delete later) in the `shared_ptr` you should do the following:

```
shared_ptr<int> r{q};
```

`make_shared` exists as a helper for creating `shared_ptr` passing arguments to the object the pointer is going to point to.

Answer (score 0):

The point of smart pointers is to maintain their memory smartly. In your case `q` is located on the stack. If you pass it to a smart pointer then it will get deleted when it is no longer referenced. This will crash your program because you can't delete memory on the stack. It is also sort of silly to want to because it is freed when `q` goes out of scope anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`make_shared<>()` takes the arguments to a constructor.

```
shared_ptr<int> r = make_shared<int>(q);
```

This constructs a shared point to a single `int` that holds the same value as `q`.

If you want to assign a pointer to a shared pointer you would do something like:

```
shared_ptr<int> r = q;
```

That being said, your particular example makes no sense.  When the shared pointer goes out of scope it will call delete on a stack allocated variable with invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Without any usage information it depends upon the lifetime. If you only need to use it during a function, you're better off with a reference.

```
auto& r = *q;
```

If you must get a pointer type you can do

```
auto& r = q;
```